# react-dnd not detecting hover and drop events

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-dnd

I'm having trouble getting react-dnd to to work.  Specifically, while I can confirm dragging is being detected properly, my droppable targets are not detecting hover or drop events.  I've been following the example at http://survivejs.com/react/implementing-kanban/drag-and-drop/ to create a draggable item.  I've tried to use a combination of the same examples and the official examples from the [official repo](http://gaearon.github.io/react-dnd/docs-tutorial.html) to create a DropTarget to accept the draggable.  However, my DropTarget is giving no indication that it is detecting the draggable.  My code below has multiple debugger statements to indicate if code is being reached, but none of them ever are. 
I suspect that the `compose` call at the end might be the problem, but I'm following Dan Abramov's example [here](https://github.com/gaearon/react-dnd/issues/373).  Just to add to the problem, the React inspector in Chrome dev tools lets me see the `itemType` state variable change as I drag an item.  However, both the `canDrop` and `isOver` state variables remain false. I'd appreciate any help to get this to work.

```
import { findDOMNode } from 'react-dom';
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import MuiThemeProvider from 'material-ui/styles/MuiThemeProvider';
import Paper from 'material-ui/Paper';
import FaDelete from 'react-icons/lib/fa/trash-o';
import RaisedButton from 'material-ui/RaisedButton';
import FaEdit from 'react-icons/lib/fa/star';
import actions from '../actions/actions';
import TextField from 'material-ui/TextField';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
//import EmojiPickerPopup from './EmojiPickerPopup';
import RenderIf from 'render-if';
import globals from '../globals';
import { DropTarget } from 'react-dnd';
import { compose } from 'redux';

const locationItemContainer = {
    display: 'flex',
    flexDirection: 'column',
    backgroundColor: 'lightgoldenrodyellow',
    border: '1px solid Moccasin',
    width: "33%",
    maxHeight: "15em"
}

const controlsContainer = {
    display: 'flex',
    flexDirection: 'row',
    justifyContent: 'space-around',
    width: "100%"
}

const paperStyle = {
    padding: '8px 4px',
    display: 'flex',
    flexDirection: "column",
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center',
    width: "100%",
    height: "100%"
};

class LocationItemComponent extends Component {
    constructor(props, context) {
        super(props, context);
        this.state = {
            locationMarkers: []
        }
    }

    componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
        if (!this.props.isOver && nextProps.isOver) {
            // You can use this as enter handler
            debugger
        }

        if (this.props.isOver && !nextProps.isOver) {
            // You can use this as leave handler
            debugger
        }

        if (this.props.isOverCurrent && !nextProps.isOverCurrent) {
            // You can be more specific and track enter/leave
            // shallowly, not including nested targets
            debugger
        }
    }

    nameChanged = (id, event, value) => {
        this.props.dispatch(actions.storyMapActions.updateMarkerName(value, id));
    }
    deleteMarker = (id) => {
        this.props.dispatch(actions.storyMapActions.deleteMarker(id));
    }
    showEmojiPicker = (id, event) => {
        this.props.dispatch(actions.modalsActions.showEmojiPicker(id, event.currentTarget))
    }
    render() {
        const { isOver, canDrop, connectDropTarget } = this.props;
        if (isOver) {
            console.log("is over");
        }
        return connectDropTarget(
            <div style={locationItemContainer}>
                <MuiThemeProvider>
                    <Paper zDepth={5}
                        style={paperStyle}
                        rounded={false}>
                        <TextField
                            id="markerName"
                            hintText="marker Name"
                            onChange={this.nameChanged.bind(this, this.props.marker.id)}
                            value={this.props.marker.name}
                            underlineFocusStyle={{ color: globals.textUnderlineColor }}
                            />
                        <div style={controlsContainer}>
                            <RaisedButton
                                icon={<FaEdit />}
                                primary={true}
                                onClick={this.showEmojiPicker.bind(this, this.props.marker.id)} />
                            <RaisedButton
                                icon={<FaDelete />}
                                secondary={true}
                                onClick={this.deleteMarker.bind(this, this.props.marker.id)} />
                        </div>
                    </Paper>
                </MuiThemeProvider>
            </div>
        );
    }
}
const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
    return Object.assign({}, { state: state });
}

const locationTarget = {
    canDrop(props, monitor) {
        debugger;
        // You can disallow drop based on props or item
        const item = monitor.getItem();
        return true;
    },

    hover(props, monitor, component) {
        debugger;
        // This is fired very often and lets you perform side effects
        // in response to the hover. You can't handle enter and leave
        // here—if you need them, put monitor.isOver() into collect() so you
        // can just use componentWillReceiveProps() to handle enter/leave.

        // You can access the coordinates if you need them
        const clientOffset = monitor.getClientOffset();
        const componentRect = findDOMNode(component).getBoundingClientRect();

        // You can check whether we're over a nested drop target
        const isJustOverThisOne = monitor.isOver({ shallow: true });

        // You will receive hover() even for items for which canDrop() is false
        const canDrop = monitor.canDrop();
    },

    drop(props, monitor, component) {
        debugger;
        if (monitor.didDrop()) {
            // If you want, you can check whether some nested
            // target already handled drop
            debugger
            return;
        }
        // Obtain the dragged item
        const item = monitor.getItem();

        // You can do something with it
        //ChessActions.movePiece(item.fromPosition, props.position);

        // You can also do nothing and return a drop result,
        // which will be available as monitor.getDropResult()
        // in the drag source's endDrag() method
        return { moved: true };
    }
};

const collect = (connect, monitor) => {
    return {
        connectDropTarget: connect.dropTarget(),
        isOver: monitor.isOver(),
        canDrop: monitor.canDrop(),
        itemType: monitor.getItemType()
    };
}

export default compose(
    connect(mapStateToProps),
    DropTarget(globals.itemTypes.LOCATION_ITEM, locationTarget, collect)

)(LocationItemComponent);
```

Comment: I know this is really old, but we'd also need to see the DragSource code. Just FYI, make sure that your DropTarget and your DragSource are both mapping to `globals.itemTypes.LOCATION_ITEM` otherwise, react-dnd will not know how to make them map to each other. I'm starting to do some react-dnd stuff and I got a working example so if this question is still an issue for you, I can maybe help.

Comment: Hello, any news on this?

Comment: The first comment was the answer for something I was working on. The type of the source and target need to be the same as per the docs: "Only the drop targets registered for the same type will react to the items produced by this drag source."